# InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience - Authentication for Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-authentication

After a couple of days of struggling, I will try to get some help here. I have several logic apps - some with HTTP triggers and some with SQL triggers (when an item is created, when an item is modified). They are running every X of hours, but the client requested to have the possibility to run the logic apps also manually through a button click in his custom web application.

To be able to run the logic apps (call the triggers), I am trying to get a Bearer token for authorization and run the logic app. I followed all these steps https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/securing-azure-logic-app-http-triggers-with-azure-ad#.
Shortly said, I created two app registrations (client and service) including role app and API permissions. Then I added into a LogicApp under Authorization the Issuer ([https://login.windows.net/{tenantid}/oauth2/token/](https://login.windows.net/%7Btenantid%7D/oauth2/token/)) and the Audience (the ClientId of the Service App registration) - that is Step 5 from the link.

But I see I am missing some understanding here. Because now when I test it (as described in the link), I have the following error.

First getting the token:

[image]

And then try to execute the LogicApp Trigger with that token:

[image]

***The access token has been obtained for wrong audience or resource 'XXX'. It should exactly match with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.core.windows.net','https://management.azure.com/','https://management.azure.com'.***

The link of the POST request is the trigger of the LogicApp like:
**[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{id}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{LogicAppName}/triggers/When_an_item_is_created/run?api-version=2016-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7Bid%7D/resourceGroups/%7BResourceGroup%7D/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/%7BLogicAppName%7D/triggers/When_an_item_is_created/run?api-version=2016-06-01)**

I know that this link works because if I try to enter my personal data (email and password), it succeeds. But to avoid username and password data in the code, I wanted to solve this with this token. But I do not know where I need to fix it so the audience matches - in the logic app or in those app registrations? I would be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered Azure AD applications same as you and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** via Postman with below parameters:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<client appID>
client_secret: <secret>
resource: api://<service appID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to execute LogicApp Trigger, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/<LogicAppName>/triggers/manual/run?api-version=2016-06-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to change your request URL by passing your **Logic App URL without SAS key**.

When I changed the request URL like that, LogicApp **triggered** sucessfully with below response:

```
POST <Logic Apps URL without SAS key>
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you want to trigger logic app with **Management REST API**, then you need to generate access token with different **resource** like this:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<client appID>
client_secret: <secret>
resource: https://management.azure.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to trigger LogicApp with Management API call, I got **response** with `Status: 202 Accepted` like below:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/<LogicAppName>/triggers/manual/run?api-version=2016-06-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

Make sure to assign **proper role** to the service principal based on your requirement, before generating access token.

In my case, I assigned **`Contributor`** role to service principal under LogicApp like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, especially for the last thing related to the role assignment, that was the missing part for me!! It works now! THANK YOU :)